# Como emitir o XML da NFe ao WS da SEFAZ usando C#?

Tags: c#, nfe

Estive fazendo muitas pesquisas, lendo diversos códigos de fonte de outras linguagens e nunca encontrei resposta para minha questão, qual método do web services da SEFAZ devo chamar?

Estou trabalhando com este WS `http://nfe.fazenda.mg.gov.br/nfe2/services/NfeRetRecepcao2?wsdl`

Ano passado em um forum, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/pt-BR/c75142b6-ad8a-43ee-9113-b2e9e9353b1b/acessando-webservice-da-nfe-da-sefaz levantei a seguinte questão:

O WS acima possui a class NfeRecepcao2SoapClient. Ao instancia-la obtemos apenas o método nfeRecepcaoLote2 que aceita argumentos pelo qual não é uma string do XML e retorna um array de Object.

Dai eu pergunto, como eu envio o XML para SEFAZ? Alguém pelo menos tem alguma noção?

Comment: Existe o projeto UniNFe, ele tem o código fonte, talvez ajude seu caso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu não uso as chamadas de webservice usando o add reference, não faça isso não. É um grande trabalho, e o Sefaz não estão padronizados, pois tem estado que está diferente.

```cs
public static String soapXmlStatusServico(string cUF, int ambiente)
{
    String result = String.Empty;
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(); // The writer closes this for us

    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("soap:Envelope");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        writer.WriteStartElement("soap:Header");
        writer.WriteStartElement("nfeCabecMsg");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2");
        writer.WriteElementString("cUF", cUF);
        writer.WriteElementString("versaoDados", "3.10");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("soap:Body");

        writer.WriteStartElement("nfeDadosMsg");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2");
        writer.WriteStartElement("consStatServ");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("versao", "3.10");
        writer.WriteElementString("tpAmb", ambiente.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("cUF", cUF);
        writer.WriteElementString("xServ", "STATUS");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Flush();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        result += reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return result;
}

private CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

public string RequestWebService(string wsURL, string param, string action, X509Certificate2 certificado)
{
    Uri urlpost = new Uri(wsURL);
    HttpWebRequest httpPostConsultaNFe = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlpost);

    string postConsultaComParametros = param;
    byte[] buffer2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postConsultaComParametros);

    httpPostConsultaNFe.CookieContainer = cookies;
    httpPostConsultaNFe.Timeout = 300000;
    httpPostConsultaNFe.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=" + action;
    httpPostConsultaNFe.Method = "POST";
    httpPostConsultaNFe.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
    httpPostConsultaNFe.ContentLength = buffer2.Length;    

    Stream PostData = httpPostConsultaNFe.GetRequestStream();
    PostData.Write(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
    PostData.Close();

    HttpWebResponse responsePost = (HttpWebResponse)httpPostConsultaNFe.GetResponse();
    Stream istreamPost = responsePost.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader strRespotaUrlConsultaNFe = new StreamReader(istreamPost, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

    return strRespotaUrlConsultaNFe.ReadToEnd();
} 

public string NFeStatusServico(string xml, int cUF, string CnpjTransmissor, bool EPEC, X509Certificate2 certificado)
{
    string Retorno = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string action = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2/nfeStatusServicoNF2";

        #region "ADDRESS"

         string am = Properties.Settings.Default.am_hom_statusServico;
         string ba = Properties.Settings.Default.ba_hom_statusServico;
         string ce = Properties.Settings.Default.ce_hom_statusServico;
         string go = Properties.Settings.Default.go_hom_statusServico;
         string mg = Properties.Settings.Default.mg_hom_statusServico;
         string mt = Properties.Settings.Default.mt_hom_statusServico;
         string ms = Properties.Settings.Default.ms_hom_statusServico;
         string pe = Properties.Settings.Default.pe_hom_statusServico;
         string pr = Properties.Settings.Default.pr_hom_statusServico;
         string rs = Properties.Settings.Default.rs_hom_statusServico;
         string sp = Properties.Settings.Default.sp_hom_statusServico;
         string svan = Properties.Settings.Default.svan_hom_statusServico;
         string svrs = Properties.Settings.Default.svrs_hom_statusServico;
         string svcan = Properties.Settings.Default.svcan_hom_statusServico;
         string svcrs = Properties.Settings.Default.svcrs_hom_statusServico;

        #endregion

        SefazWebRequest request = new SefazWebRequest();

        #region "UF AUTORIZADORAS"
        switch (cUF)
        {
            case (int)
                Estados.AM:
                    if(EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(am, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.BA:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(ba, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.CE:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(ce, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.GO:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(go, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.MG:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(mg, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.MS:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(ms, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.MT:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(mt, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.PE:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(pe, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.PR:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(pr, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.RS:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(rs, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
            case (int)Estados.SP:
                    if (EPEC)
                    {
                        //Envio Emissao Previa de Entrada em contingencia
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retorno = request.RequestWebService(sp, xml, action, certificado);
                    }
                    break;
        }
        #endregion

        #region "SVRS - SEFAZ VIRTUAL RIO GRANDE DO SUL = AC, AL, AP, DF, ES, PB, RJ, RN, RO, RR, SC, SE, TO "

        if (cUF == (int)Estados.AC ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.AL ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.AP ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.DF ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.ES ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.PB ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.RJ ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.RN ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.RO ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.RR ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.SC ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.SE ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.TO)
        {
            if (EPEC)
            {    
            }
            else
            {
                Retorno = request.RequestWebService(svrs, xml, action, certificado);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region "SEFAZ VIRTUAL AMBIENTE NACIONAL = MA, PA, PI"

        if (cUF == (int)Estados.MA ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.PA ||
            cUF == (int)Estados.PI)
        {
            if (EPEC)
            {    
            }
            else
            {
                Retorno = request.RequestWebService(svan, xml, action, certificado);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }   
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        eventos.AppLog("NFeStatusServico", ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
    return Retorno;
}
```

Comment: Eu estava fazendo justamente isto, nunca iria imaginar que não deveria usar este caminho.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45430/como-enviar-o-xml-da-nfe-consumindo-o-webservice-da-sefaz